# VBScript & Outlook 2010: Cannot save mail item as text file

Tags: vbscript, outlook-2010

I have an issue with saving an Outlook 2010 email item as a text file using VBScript.  I am beginning to think it is a permissions issue, but the VBScript error message is not very helpful:

> myscript.vbs(409, 9) (null): Operation aborted

Code looks like this:

```
' create an object to hold a folder item - 
' point it to first item
set olitem = olitems(1)
if err.number <> 0 then
    stdout.write("Could not create Outlook Item object - exiting" & vbcrlf)
    stdout.write("Err.Number: " & Err.Number & vbcrlf)
    wscript.quit(999)
end if


' save the mail item to a text file
olitem.saveas fullpath_src & messagefilename, oltxt
if err.number <> 0 then
    stdout.write("Could not save email as a text file - exiting" & vbcrlf)
    stdout.write("Err.Number: " & Err.Number & vbcrlf)
    wscript.quit(999)
end if
```

`oltxt` is defined as a `Const` of value `0` - the value for a text file.

I get the same error if I try to process an email's body text under Outlook 2010. Under Outlook 2013 - on a different, non-corporate, machine - the code works fine.

I think I read somewhere that some Outlook 2010 functionality may have been crippled under certain circumstances for security reasons - revolving around the presence/absence of antivirus software.  If this is true, I have been stopped in my tracks - even though I have corporate grade AV protection.

Comment: This is likely a permissions issue, the error itself is coming from COM *(a lot of discussions on the internet about this error in relation to Outlook)*. What does `fullpath_src` point, is it a local path or a network path?

Comment: @Lankymart - fullpath_src points to a fully-qualified, backslash-terminated  local directory, e.g. "C:\some\dir\"

Comment: How do you execute the script, is it executed with elevated privileges?